# Is there anything like viewDidLoad for the loading of the app's main xib?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nib, xib, uiapplicationdelegate

As in the one defined with "Main nib file base name" in the app's Info.plist. Should I just use `applicationDidFinishLaunching`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` gets called after the main nib has been loaded.

Also, according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW29) (for iPhone OS 3.0):

> It is recommended that you implement
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>   instead of this method. See the class
>   description for the differences in
>   calling sequences between the two
>   methods.